# Java Console Calendar in 2 Column

Tags: java, api, calendar, console

Hi guys i really need your help. I need to output a 3 year calendar in 3 columns. In the first column the year should be the year that the user input.

I have a code that will post a 3 year calendar but only in 1 column. I need to separate the other year in another column plss help me

```
package project;

import java.util.*;

public class les1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String ans;
        // getting the system calendar's year, maximum days,
        // weeks per month and system calendar's month.
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int day = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int col[] = new int[3];

        do {
            // validation for input year

            do {
                System.out.print("\nEnter year: ");
                while (true)
                    try {
                        year = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Try again!");
                        System.out.print("\nEnter year: ");
                    }
                if (year < 1900 || year > 2099) {
                    System.out.println("Try again!");
                }
            } while (year < 1900 || year > 2099);

            /*
             * System.out.println("enter number of elements");
             * 
             * int n = in.nextInt();
             * 
             * int arr[] = new int[n];
             * 
             * for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {// for reading array
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * for (int j : arr) {
             */
            // loop for months
                for (month = 1; month <= 1; month++) {
                    // calculating years, month, days and weeks.
                    int y = year - (14 - month) / 12;
                    int x = y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400;
                    int m = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
                    int d = (1 + x + (31 * m) / 12) % 7;
                    // calculate leap year
                    boolean LeapYear = (year % 400 == 0);
                    // displaying month as String
                    cal.set(year, month, 0);
                        System.out
                                .print(cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH) + "\t\t\t\t\t\t");
                        System.out.print("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat" + "\t\t\t");

                    int length = (int) (30 + ((month + (month / 8.0)) % 2));
                    if (month == 2) {
                        if (LeapYear) {
                            length -= 1;
                        } else {
                            length -= 2;
                        }
                    }

                    for (int a = 0; a < col.length; a++) {
                        int counter = 1;
                        // spacing for first day of the month
                        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                            System.out.print("    ");
                            counter++;
                        }
                        // spacing for days
                        for (day = 1; day <= length; day++) {
                            System.out.printf("%2d", day);
                            System.out.print((counter++ % 7 != 0) ? "  " : "\n");
                        }
                    }
                    week = (week + length) % 6;
                }
            year++;
            /* } */
            System.out.print("\n\n" + "Enter another year (Y/N)? ");
            ans = in.next();
        } while (ans.equals("Y") || ans.equals("y"));
        System.out.println("\nEnd!");
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 3 year calendar? please explain in details what is your expected output of each columns and what are you getting as output?

Comment: For example I will input 2015, then the console will display the calendar of year 2015 in 1st column then the calendar of year 2016 in 2nd column then the calendar of year 2017 in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code. It will print three different years' calendars in three columns. I have used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) formula to determine the day of the week in any month.

```
 import java.util.*;

 public class les1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] days = {
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
    };
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String ans;
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int col[] = new int[3];

    do {
        // validation for input year

        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter year: ");
            while (true)
            try {
                year = Integer.parseInt( in .next());
                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Try again!");
                System.out.print("\nEnter year: ");
            }
            if (year < 1900 || year > 2099) {
                System.out.println("Try again!");
            }
        } while (year < 1900 || year > 2099);

        for (month = 1; month <= 1; month++) {


            HashMap < Integer, Integer > map = new HashMap < Integer, Integer > ();
            map.put(1, 0);
            map.put(7, 6);
            map.put(2, 3);
            map.put(8, 2);
            map.put(3, 3);
            map.put(9, 5);
            map.put(4, 6);
            map.put(10, 0);
            map.put(5, 1);
            map.put(11, 3);
            map.put(6, 4);
            map.put(12, 5);

            System.out.println();

            for (int a = 0; a < col.length; a++) {
                int counter = 1;
                System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
                System.out.printf("\t\t\t"); //Formatting for days

            }
            // System.out.println();

            // calculate leap year
            boolean LeapYear = false;
            if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) LeapYear = true;
            // displaying month as String

            ArrayList < Integer > dds = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
            dds.add(0);
            dds.add(0);
            dds.add(0);
            dds.add(0);
            int indexofA = 0;

            String yy = year + "";

            int m;
            if (LeapYear && month == 1) m = map.get(month) + 6;
            else if (LeapYear && month == 2) m = map.get(month) - 1;
            else m = map.get(month);

            int y = Integer.parseInt(yy.substring(2, 4));
            int c = (year / 100);
            if (c % 4 == 0) c = 6;
            else if (c % 4 == 1) c = 4;
            else if (c % 4 == 2) c = 2;
            else c = 0;
            int x = y + y / 4 + c;
            int d = (1 + x + m) % 7;
            // cal.set(year, month, 0);

            int length = (int)(30 + ((month + (month / 8.0)) % 2));
            if (month == 2) {
                if (LeapYear) {
                    length -= 1;
                } else {
                    length -= 2;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("len : " + length);
            System.out.println();
            boolean thirtyone = false;
            int count = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) { //For each row of the calendars

                String[] dayss = new String[7];

                int index = 0;

                for (int a = 0; a < col.length; a++) { //For each column of a calendar

                    for (int i = 0; i < d && dds.get(indexofA) == 0; i++) {

                        dayss[index] = " ";
                        index++;
                    }

                    for (day = dds.get(indexofA) + 1; day <= length; day++) {
                        if (day == 31) {
                            dayss[index] = day + "";
                            index++;
                            thirtyone = true;

                        } else if (day < 31) {
                            dayss[index] = day + "";
                            index++;
                        }

                        if (index == 7) {
                            dds.set(indexofA, day);
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    indexofA++;
                    System.out.printf("%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s", dayss[0], dayss[1], dayss[2], dayss[3],
                    dayss[4], dayss[5], dayss[6]);
                    System.out.printf("\t\t\t");

                    index = 0;
                    year++;
                    LeapYear = false;
                    if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) LeapYear = true;
                    yy = year + "";
                    if (LeapYear && month == 1) m = map.get(month) + 6;
                    else if (LeapYear && month == 2) m = map.get(month) - 1;
                    else m = map.get(month);

                    y = Integer.parseInt(yy.substring(2, 4));
                    c = (year / 100);
                    if (c % 4 == 0) c = 6;
                    else if (c % 4 == 1) c = 4;
                    else if (c % 4 == 2) c = 2;
                    else c = 0;
                    x = y + y / 4 + c;
                    d = (1 + x + m) % 7;

                }
                year -= 3;
                yy = year + "";
                LeapYear = false;
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) LeapYear = true;

                if (LeapYear && month == 1) m = map.get(month) + 6;
                else if (LeapYear && month == 2) m = map.get(month) - 1;
                else m = map.get(month);

                y = Integer.parseInt(yy.substring(2, 4));
                c = (year / 100);
                if (c % 4 == 0) c = 6;
                else if (c % 4 == 1) c = 4;
                else if (c % 4 == 2) c = 2;
                else c = 0;
                x = y + y / 4 + c;
                d = (1 + x + m) % 7;

                indexofA = 0;
                System.out.println();

            }

        }
        System.out.print("\n\n" + "Enter another year (Y/N)? ");
        ans = in .next();
    } while (ans.equals("Y") || ans.equals("y"));
    System.out.println("\nEnd!"); in .close();
}

}
```